# How does return work here?

Tags: c, int, boolean, return

## new question: but why the expression from n == number, from firstFactorPtr == factor1 ?

Can somebody explain me, how this works:

> return ( factor == 1 );

This returns to "main" with "factor == 1 " , why does "isPrime" return true?
And why does it return false if we "*firstFactorPtr" and "*secondFactorPtr" ?
It is searching for prime numbers and for non prime numbers.
There is no "int factor" in "main", how can it return to "main" with any expression?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <math.h>


    bool Factor( int number, int *firstFactorPtr, int *secondFactorPtr );

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
    int n;

for ( n = 5; n <= 20; n++ ) {
    bool isPrime;
    int factor1, factor2;
    
    isPrime = Factor( n, &factor1, &factor2 );
    if ( isPrime )
        printf( "the number %d is prime\n", n );
    else
        printf( "the number %d has %d and %d as factors\n", n, factor1, factor2 );
    }

  return 0;
 }


 bool Factor( int number, int *firstFactorPtr, int *secondFactorPtr )
 {
if ( number < 1 )
    return false;   

int factor; 
for ( factor = sqrt(number); factor > 1; factor-- ) {
    if ( (number % factor) == 0 ) {
        break;
    }
}

*firstFactorPtr = factor;
*secondFactorPtr = number / factor;
return ( factor == 1 );
 }
```

Comment: It returns `true` if the input number is prime (supposedly). Your loop should stop as soon as a factor > 1 is found. If not (it reaches 1, i.e. `factor == 1`) then the number is prime.

Comment: so if "factor == 1" it return "true", if any else - false?

Comment: Yes, return true or false, dependent on `factor` *reaching* `1` and thereby exhausting possible factors (1 is a rather boring factor). If the function returns `true`, the value passed in is, as far as you are concerned, prime.

Comment: why it return true/false when any expression? because it bool?

Comment: @cvxc Imagine that the expression is inside an if(): if(factor == 1) { foo(); }. C is evaluating the expression (factor == 1) and assigning it a true/false value. If factor is 1, then the expression evaluates to true. If factor is anything other than 1, then the expression evaluates to false.

Comment: ok! but why n = number? from bool Factor to main?

Comment: but why the expression from n == number, from firstFactorPtr == factor1 ?

Comment: and why "bool" Factor whatever void?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing your `Factor` function:

```
bool Factor( /* ... */ )
{
    int factor;
    /* ... */
    factor = /* some value */;
    /* ... */
    return ( factor == 1 );
}
```

The simple explanation is that the expression `( factor == 1 )` is true if `factor` is equal to `1`, false if it's unequal. This value, either true or false, is returned from the function. A call to the function is a Boolean expression, just like a call to a function that returns an `int` is an `int` expression. Which means that you can write something like this:

```
/* some computations */
if (factor == 1) {
    /* do something */
}
```

you can write this:

```
if (Factor( /* arguments */ )) {
    /* do something */
}
```

with the computations performed inside the `Factor` function.

Boolean values like "true" and "false" are just values, and they can be manipulated like any other values like `42` or `1.23`.

But it's a bit more complicated than that.

`==` is the equality operator. There's nothing particularly special about it; like any other operator (`+` for addition, `/` for division, etc.) it takes one or more operands of some type(s) and yields a result of some type.

`+` yields the sum of its operands; the type of the result depends on the type of the operands.

`==` yields a result of type `int`. That result is `1` if the operands are equal to each other, `0` if they're not. In this case, the operands `factor` and `1` are of the same numeric type, `int`, so the comparison is valid; there are fairly complicated rules for `==` on other scalar types, but we needn't worry about them here.

For historical reasons, the result is *not* of type `bool`, though that would make more sense. C didn't even have a Boolean type until the 1999 standard; rather, it's of type `int`. Any scalar (integer, floating-point, or pointer) expression can be used in a Boolean context (`if`, `while`, etc.), treated as false if it's equal to `0` and true otherwise.

So if the value of `factor` happens to be `1` when the return statement is executed, it will return the value `1`.

Your `Factor` function is defined to return a result of type `bool`, not `int`. So the value of the expression is implicitly converted from `int` (the type yielded by `==`) to `bool` (the type of the function result). The result of that conversion is simply `1`, but of type `bool` rather than `int`. That value can also be spelled as `true` since you've `#include`d `<stdbool.h>`, which defines `true` as a macro.

(Some other languages have had a Boolean type from the beginning. In such a language, the expression `( factor == 1 )` would yield a Boolean value of "true", and that value would be returned by the function, with no conversion necessary. The behavior would be conceptually simpler than what happens in C, but the result would be essentially the same. When `<stdbool.h>` was added to the language, along with the type `_Bool` and the macros `false` and `true`, it was done in a way that makes it convenient to write code that uses the new built-in Boolean type *without* breaking existing code that uses `int` or other scalar types for Boolean values and operations.)

Answer (score 1):

It returns the result of the Boolean expression "factor equals 1", i.e., `true` or `false`.

This routine also has a side effect: it stores the found factorials in the lists pointed to by the two int * in the header.

In essence, it returns `true` if the factor is a prime -- the loop counted down all the way to '1' --, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

return (factor == 1) means 'return true if factor == 1, return false if factor != 1'. The function called Factor() returns true if the value of the 'factor' variable went all the way down to 1 (meaning that it couldn't find any factors for the 'number' variable). The function returns false if 'factor' did not make it all the way down to 1, meaning that it was able to find at least one factor for 'number'.

Comment: but why the expression from n == number, from firstFactorPtr == factor1 ?

Comment: @cvxc I'm not sure I understand your question. The code says *firstFactorPtr = factor (note the single '='). This is an assignment, not an expression, and it's not related to the return value. I'm not really clear on what you're asking. What do you mean by 'n == number' and 'firstFactorPtr == factor1'? Neither of those expressions appears in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`factor` counts all the way down from `sqrt` to 2. If there is a factor which is divisible by the `number`, it breaks out of the for loop. Thus `factor` contains the one of the divisors of number. So the divisor is held by `*firstFactor` and the second divisor is held by `*secondFactorPtr`. Note that these are the same pointers which your main() function has passed to `Factor`. So in the main() function you will find that `factor1` and `factor2` are populated with 2 factors.

If it does not find any factor greater than 1, then it contains 1 and breaks out of the for loop. If it does not find a factor, then the only factos are 1 and the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```
 return foo == bar;
```

is equivalent to

```
 return foo == bar ? 1 : 0;
```

since relational operators like `==` yield either 0 or 1. Does that make it clear?